# Does a C# Task run on one core?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Does a C# Task run on one core?

I have a project where I need to decide how many Tasks to create.
I need to create as many, as the computer can take.
Is that the number of processors, cores, or logical processors, I am
confused between the three options.

Comment: As I understand it, a managed thread is not even necessarily run on its own native thread. So I think the answer to your question is "neither."

Comment: A task works very much like a thread for which core it runs on (I believe). To answer your questions it depends on what your tasks are doing which resource are they using the most of  CPU / IO / Memory / Disk ...?

Comment: A Task can hop from one core to another.  What you should really ask is "does a task run on more than one core?".  No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A task executes on a thread. The OS schedules threads to cores. Cores are a logical concept and different from physical CPU chips.

Create `Environment.ProcessorCount` tasks, or better use one of the higher level TPL constructs like PLINQ or `Parallel` .

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Task library (PTL), you won't need to worry about this. You can read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx). In a nutshell:

> The TPL scales the degree of concurrency dynamically to most efficiently use all the processors that are available. In addition, the TPL handles the partitioning of the work...

We've created a wrapper around Task as follows:

```
public static class PeriodicTaskFactory
{
    public static Task Start(Action action, int intervalInMilliseconds = -1, int delayInMilliseconds = 0, int duration = -1, int maxIterations = -1, bool synchronous = false, CancellationToken cancelToken = null, TaskCreationOptions periodicTaskCreationOptions = TaskCreationOptions.None);
}
```

And then we call it like so. In this case, the only work we want to perform is calling a single method every 1 minutes, with a 1 second delay in the first execute.

```
        PeriodicTaskFactory.Start(() =>
        {
            CdClMappingLogic.Invoke();
        }, 60000, 1000, -1, -1, true)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Yes I am reading that document actually.

Comment: Basically what he is saving here is that you in TPL you define the work and let the framework work out how many threads ... etc to create. You just define what each thread is to do.

Comment: @user2381422 - Yes, as TheKingDave said, it is very simple to use. You define what work you want to perform, wrap it in a task and the .NET FW decides how best to execute that block of work based on cpu's, and other resources.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460705.aspx is a good example of how the TPL works out scheduling of the Task(s).

Comment: I have a List, and each Task needs to take one element from there and compute something. I am confused how would they share that List?

Comment: @user2381422 - I've included an example in my response.

Comment: @RandyMinder I don't know how that relates to my question for sharing a List :(

Comment: @user2381422 - Your original question does not mention sharing a list. It asks about creating tasks and how best to take advantage of cpu(s) to execute them. Sharing a list amoung multiple tasks is a completely different question.