# Using tasks for repeated actions

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have 50 Machine Learning agents. Every frame, they get some inputs and compute the neural network. Because every agent is independent, I would like to make every agent compute the network as a separate task.

If I were to create a task for every agent, each frame, it will make my program slower. I tried to group my agents into 2 tasks (25 and 25), but it was still an overhead.

The way I see it, is to create n threads for n groups of agents at the beginning and query those threads each frame, somehow. A thread would compute the network for the group of agents, then wait until the next query.

I have read some articles on this topic, and I found out I can't reuse a task. So, what workaround could work?

Basically, I have a repeated action on 50 agents, that is run every frame, for about a minute, and it would be a waste not to parallelize them.

I am still new to multithreading and tasks, so I am relying on your help.

---

Side notes: I'm using Genetic Algorithms in Unity.

---

Here is the code in which I have tried to divide the agents in n groups, and compute their networks in n tasks.

```
public async Task EvaluateAsync(int groupSize = 10)
{
    var groups = genomes.Select((g, i) => new { Value = g, Index = i })
                        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / groupSize)
                        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value));

    var tasks = groups.Select(g =>
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            foreach (var element in g)
                element.Fitness += ComputeFitness(element as NeuralGenome);
        });
    }).ToArray();

    for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
        await tasks[i];
}
```

And in the `Update()` function I call:

```
EvaluateAsync(25).Wait();
```

It is a bit faster when the network is very very big, but it's much slower when there are only 10 neurons.

Making the groups smaller, would result in a better performance only if the networks are very huge.

Here I create a task for each agent:

```
public async Task EvaluateAsyncEach()
{
    var tasks = genomes.Select(x => Task.Run(() => x.Fitness += ComputeFitness(x as NeuralGenome)))
                       .ToArray();
    foreach (var task in tasks)
        await task;
}
```

The following measurements are made for 10 frames. Meaning, t/10 will be the time for one task.

Time for normal running:

```
00:00:00.3791190
00:00:00.3758430
00:00:00.3697020
00:00:00.3743900
00:00:00.3764850
```

One task for each agent each frame:

```
00:00:01.1288240
00:00:01.0761770
00:00:00.9311210
00:00:01.0122570
00:00:00.8938200
```

In groups of 25:

```
00:00:00.5401100
00:00:00.5629660
00:00:00.5640470
00:00:00.5932220
00:00:00.6053940
00:00:00.5828170
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18059569/1132334; parallelization makes sense if two conditions are met: 1) if one task is doing sufficient work to saturate the logical core its scheduled to run on (ie. not yielding/waiting most of the time), then the number of tasks should not exceed the number of available cores. also your process may not be the only process on the machine. 2) the time to complete a task should be significantly higher than the time spent for task creation+scheduling. I doubt that 2) is the problem here. do you have metrics to support the claim of "still an overhead"?

Comment: Creating a task is pretty lightweight, and is probably dwarfed by the computational power necessary to comput a neural net. I think you’re working on the wrong problem.

Comment: @dlatikay I've just added the time measurements.

Comment: @JohnWu I've heard it's easy to parallelize reinforcement learning agents.

Comment: @JohnWu I thought, maybe I should create a thread for n groups of agents at the start, and query those threads each frame somehow.

Comment: @unicornslayer - It would be good if you could post your benchmarking code so I could validate and compare my answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this. It is ideally suited to this kind of processing.

Here's the code:

```
var query =
    from genome in genomes.ToObservable()
    from fitness in Observable.Start(() => ComputeFitness(genome as NeuralGenome))
    select new { genome, fitness };

IDisposable subscription =
    query.Subscribe(x => x.genome.Fitness += x.fitness);
```

It does all of its own thread/task management under the hood. It also produces results as soon as possible as they get computed.

If you want to be able to `await` the results you can do it this way:

```
var query =
    from genome in genomes.ToObservable()
    from fitness in Observable.Start(() => ComputeFitness(genome as NeuralGenome))
    select new { genome, fitness };

var results = await query.ToArray();

foreach (var x in results)
{
    x.genome.Fitness += x.fitness;
}
```

Just NuGet "System.Reactive" and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` to your query.

---

Based on the code in your comment, I think you should look at this instead:

```
private async Task ComputingNetworksAsync()
{
    var query =
        from a in agents.ToObservable()
        let i = a.GenerateNetworkInputs()
        from n in Observable.Start(() => a.ComputeNetwork(i))
        select n;

    await query.ToArray();
}
```

That's a direct equivalent to your code (except for the `.ToArray()`).

However, you can go one step further and do this:

```
private async Task ComputingNetworksAsync()
{
    var query =
        from a in agents.ToObservable()
        from i in Observable.Start(() => a.GenerateNetworkInputs())
        from n in Observable.Start(() => a.ComputeNetwork(i))
        select n;

    await query.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The movement is computed each "Physics Frame", so it must be awaited... I suppose. Isn't your second example just the same as using Task.Run(), if it's awaited, or am I missing something? I actually have a different situation, but the idea is the same, so here is what I do at each Frame, but it's still an overhead: [link](https://gist.github.com/TermanEmil/215b821930054abe790f3ac916b5049a)

Comment: I suppose @JohnWu is right, I don't need to parallelize them after all

Comment: @unicornslayer - I've added some more code for you to look at in my answer. Also, I don't think my second example is "just the same" - it's certainly similar because it is trying to do the same thing, but it's got a cleaner execution model that tasks. The `Task` approach creates a bunch of tasks that generate side-effects that you must await. The `Observable` approach doesn't have side-effects inside the observable - all changes happen outside of it. That's what you want to avoid concurrency issues.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good article.

http://fintechexplained.blogspot.com/2018/05/top-ten-tips-for-implementing-multi.html?m=1

Your solution is PLINQ. Avoid creating new tasks

Comment: Please don't link to external sites. Put the content in your answer and only link to support that content.

Comment: So you want me to copy paste entire article? I don't think thats the right approach. Here is the link that has a large number of useful information. We shouldn't copy paste contents for sake of copying pasting.

Comment: No, I don't want you copying an entire article and it's not for the sake of copying. It shouldn't be copying at all. You should put your own content in the answer and then only link to support your content. This is done to avoid answers becoming broken if the linked site goes away or changes their URLs etc.

Comment: I want you to read my answer again. I mentioned that Plinq should be used here and then referred a link Mentioning that it has better information. If link ever goes down, for the sake of argument, even then answer that Plinq should be chosen is there. You should read answer again.

Comment: No, the idea should be that your answer contains the sufficient and necessary information for the OP to solve their problem **without the need** to do any further reading or Google search to get what they need. Once your answer is to that standard then you can add links.